# dplyr filter out rows with certain pairs of strings after "X" number of rows

Tags: r, string, dplyr, filter

I am trying to filter out pairs of strings after 2 of those pairs have occurred. For instance, here is some example data:

```
String 1     String 2
QQQ          S-7
QQQ          S-8
QQQ          S-10
WWW          S-7
WWW          S-7
WWW          S-7
WWW          S-8
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-8
```

Now I would like to try and filter these with dplyr to only pull the **first two** instances of each pair. So ideally, the data ends up filtered out to look something like this:

```
String 1     String 2
QQQ          S-7
QQQ          S-8
QQQ          S-10
WWW          S-7
WWW          S-7
WWW          S-8
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-8
```

In this case, one of the "WWW S-7" pairs is gone (because two already existed) and two of the "EEE S-10" pairs are gone (because two already existed).

I'd also like to note that in the environment for this project I do not have the latest version of dplyr and also cannot get it. So I somehow have to manage with syntax that does not include things like `slice_head`, which is likely to have been ideal for this situation.

I tried to accomplish the above with code such as:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(String 1) %>% filter(String 2, n = 2)
```

and

```
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(String 1) %>% top_n(String 2, 2)
```

Neither of which worked for reasons that I am likely too amateur to understand.

Thank you all in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `filter` statement with `row_number() <= 2` grouped by both columns:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 2, .by = c(String_1, String_2))

# or for older versions of dplyr

df %>%
  group_by(String_1, String_2) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 2)
```

Output:

```
#  String_1 String_2
#1      QQQ      S-7
#2      QQQ      S-8
#3      QQQ     S-10
#4      WWW      S-7
#5      WWW      S-7
#6      WWW      S-8
#7      EEE     S-10
#8      EEE     S-10
#9      EEE      S-8
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "String_1     String_2
QQQ          S-7
QQQ          S-8
QQQ          S-10
WWW          S-7
WWW          S-7
WWW          S-7
WWW          S-8
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-10
EEE          S-8", h = TRUE)
```